# Compiling LAMP from source - apache2 error "no MPM package installed"

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I've compiled LAMP from source on a Ubuntu VPS. I had to remove a previously installed version of Apache then I manually compiled all the packages, which seems to have worked up unto a point - when I try to run commands like "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart" I get the following error - No apache MPM package installed. I have deliberately not used apt-get to install anything and want to avoid this if possible. Anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: oh, btw, the question really belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile with `--with-mpm=<MPM>`, see [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/configure.html)

Comment: Thanks Kimvais - missed that part in the docs. Oh and i'll post on serverfault.com next time